# Rejection because of unhandled promise in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, response-headers, unhandled-promise-rejection

Hope you are all doing fine!
I am running with some difficulties when I want to deploy this api. I keep on receiving the message:"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection"
My guess is that I am sending a response twice, but I cannot determine where. Does anyone know what could be going on?

```
router.post('/add', async (req, res) => {
  const friend = await User.findOne({username:req.body.friend})
  const user = await User.findById(req.body.id)

  if(friend && friend != req.headers.username) {
    user.friends.find((x) => {
      switch(friend.username){
        case user.username:{
          res.status(401).json({
            status: "Failed",
            message: "We are sorry but you cant add yourself as friend",
            data:null
        
          })
        }

        case x.friend_username: {
          res.status(401).json({
            status: "Error",
            message: `Sorry, your friend has been already added`,
            data: []
          })
        }

        default: {
          User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, {
            $addToSet:{
              friends: {
                friend_id: friend.id,
                friend_username: friend.username
              }
            }
          }, {
            upsert: true,
            safe: true
          })  
            .then(result => {
              res.status(200).json({
                status: "Success",
                message: `Friend has been added correctly! `,
                data: result
              })
            })   
            .catch((err)=>{
              res.status(500).json({
                status: "Failed",
                message: "Database Error",
                data: err
              })
            })
          }
        }  
     })
   } else {
     res.status(404).json({
       status: "Failed",
       message: "We are sorry but the username was not found",
       data:null
     })
     console.log(`There has been an failed attempt of adding a new user. \nUser: ${req.headers.username} `)
  }
})
```

`

Comment: Are you using `mongoose`?

Comment: There's so much wrong with this it's really hard to tell what the exact problem is: you've got a route handler that's way too long (extract some of the logic into functions) no break statements to prevent switch fall through, shotgun formatting (most of which I fixed for you), etc. etc. That being said the problem is likely that one of your db calls throws or the switch fall through is unintended and causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try catch block might help with debugging. And it must be used with async/await to catch unhandled promises.
I am assuming that the problem is somewhere within  User.findOne() or User.findById(). Ether they are working incorrectly, ether you're passing data in request incorrectly.

```html
router.post('/add', async(req,res)=>{
  try {
        const friend = await User.findOne({username:req.body.friend})
        const user = await User.findById(req.body.id)

        if(friend&&friend!=req.headers.username){

          user.friends.find((x)=>{

            switch(friend.username){
              case user.username:{
                res.status(401).json({
                  status: "Failed",
                  message: "We are sorry but you cant add yourself as friend",
                  data:null

              })
              }
              case x.friend_username:{
                res.status(401).json({
                  status: "Error",
                  message: `Sorry, your friend has been already added`,
                  data: []
                })
              }
              default:{

                User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id,{

                  $addToSet:{friends:{
                    friend_id:friend.id,
                    friend_username:friend.username
                  }}
                    },{upsert:true,safe:true})

                      .then(result=>{
                        res.status(200).json({
                          status: "Success",
                          message: `Friend has been added correctly! `,
                          data: result
                            })
                      })

                    .catch((err)=>{
                      res.status(500).json({
                        status: "Failed",
                        message: "Database Error",
                        data: err
                       })
                      })
                  }
                   }  }
                   )}
         else{
        res.status(404).json({
            status: "Failed",
            message: "We are sorry but the username was not found",
            data:null
        })
        console.log(`There has been an failed attempt of adding a new user. \nUser: ${req.headers.username} `)

      }
      } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
      }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

The combination of find() and switch without breaks is probably at the cause, and certainly scrambles the logic.

There are a few other things in the code that can be improved, also. Here's an edit with the changes described in comments...

```
router.post('/add',async(req,res)=>{
  // surround the async calls with try/catch
  try {
    const friend = await User.findOne({ username:req.body.friend });
    const user = await User.findById(req.body.id);

    // detect and throw app-level errors. do the express response in the catch
    // get the most basic out of the way first. we need a user and a friend for the rest of the route to work
    if (!user || !friend) {
      throw {
        status: 404,
        json: {
          status: "Failed",
          message: "user id or friend name not found",
          data: null
        } 
      }
    }

    // user adding themself as a friend doesn't need a loop to check
    if (friend.username === user.username) {
      throw {
        status: 401,
        json: {
          status: "Failed",
          message: "We are sorry but you cant add yourself as friend",
          data:null
        }
      }
    }

    // the loop that's needed here is hidden in includes()
    if (user.friends.includes(friend.username)) {
      throw {
        status: 401,
        json: {
          status: "Error",
          message: `Sorry, your friend has been already added`,
          data:null
        }
      }
    }
    // now, all of the errors have been detected and thrown
    // do the upsert with another await and send good status
    const addToSet = {
      $addToSet:{friends:{
        friend_id:friend.id,
        friend_username:friend.username
      }}
    };
    // note we await here (not then) since that's the style chosen above
    const result = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, addToSet,{ upsert:true, safe:true });
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "Success",
      message: `Friend has been added correctly! `,
      data: result
    });
  
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(error.status).json(error.json);
  }
}
```